# Write content of array in foreach

Tags: powershell

What U want to achieve is the following. I have these two lines of code:

```
$array = Get-Content C:\Management\Users.txt
foreach ($arr in $array) {
  Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $_":\Agenda"
}
```

This gives me a long list of folder permissions for all users in `Users.txt`. But the problem is, it doesnt display for which user it's retrieving the information. So I want `$arr` to be written on the screen just before the `Get-MailboxFolderPermission` is executed. I did a lot of tries, and one of them should make it clear what I want to archieve

```
foreach ($arr in $array) {
  Write-Host $arr , Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $_":\Agenda"
}
```

But this doesnt work. How can I just add the content out of `$arr` to the output on the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things wrong with your current loop:

`Write-Host` and `Get-MailboxFolderPermission` should be two separate statements, so you need to separate them with a semicolon `;` or a line break, rather than a comma `,` after `Write-Host`.

Second, when you use `foreach($arr in $array){ }`, you need to refer to `$arr` inside the loop body, rather than `$_`:

```
foreach ($arr in $array) { 
    Write-Host $arr
    Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $arr":\Agenda"
}
```

or

```
foreach ($arr in $array) { write-host $arr; Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $arr":\Agenda"}
```

---

An alternative would be to add the `$arr` value to each mailbox folder permission object with `Select-Object`:

```
foreach ($arr in $array) {
    Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $arr":\Agenda" |
        Select-Object *,{ Name="Mailbox"; Expression={$arr} }
}
```